# Matrix representation of the skew-symmetric operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, skew-symmetric-matrices

Assume that $A$ is a skew-symmetric (skew-hermitian) operator on the  finite dimensional  unitary vector space $V$.   I'm interested in the matrix representation of this operator.  I found that there exists an orthonormal basis such that entries on the principal diagonal in the  matrix  are all equal to $0$ and all $2 \times 2$ blocks on diagonal are of the form $\left( \begin{matrix}  0 & -a\\ a &0 \end{matrix} \right) $.

My question is: does there exist a basis in which the matrix of the  operator is a diagonal matrix of the form
$\left( \begin{matrix}
  \lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  0 & \lambda_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
   \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
    0 & 0 & 0&  \lambda_n
 \end{matrix} \right) $ where $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, such a basis always exists since $A$ is normal if it is skew-symmetric. *Proof*:
$$A^* = -A \iff A^*A = -AA = A(-A) = AA^*$$
And by the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Normal_matrices), normal matrices are unitarily diagonalizable which can be interpreted as - there always exists a basis in which the transformation matrix corresponding to the transformation that $A$ induces is diagonal.

Comment: Does it also hold for complex unitary space? And one more thing which I forgot to write in the question: does the representation with zeros and 2×2 skew-symmetric blocks on principal diagonal exists in complex vector space or only in real space?

Comment: @user121 It **only** holds in complex unitary space since (non-zero) skew-symmetric operators have non-real eigenvalues